# How to return multiple values out of the get method a c# class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am writing a Timer script in unity. I am attempting to define a bool variable finished, as started but not running if it is called.

```
bool finished
{
    get
    {
        return started;
        return !running;
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I am getting a warning saying line 29 (return !running) is unreachable. There are no warning messages, if the only thing I return is !running. The internet did not have clear answers to this question.

Thanks for helping me out. I got an answer, thanks.

Comment: `return started && !running;`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm a beginner, that works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio warns you that anycode after a `return` statement will not be reached, which is why `return !running;` is not reachable

You probably want to know `return started && !running`, which means that your timer did start and is no longer running.

Answer (score 0):

No code is executed after `return started;`. Therefore `return !running;` will never be reached.